# Is it possible to specify the name of the output file in a Foundry transform?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I have a PySpark transform in Palantir Foundry that's outputting to a csv file for export into other systems.

Currently, using the `write_dataframe` method the name of the file looks like this:

> spark/part-00002-cfba77d5-c6ce-4b2a-ac9a-59173c7ede5a-c000.snappy.csv

is it possible to specify a filename, such as "my_export.csv" ?

Answer (score 2):

It's likely easier to accomplish this using an export task rather than via a transform. [Some documentation on export tasks is available here](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/data-connection/export-overview/), but it is described in more detail in the in-platform docs.

If you're using a file system or SFTP export task, there is an option to rewrite paths in the task config. For example,

```
rewritePaths:
  ".*": "my_export.csv"
```

would rename all files to `my_export.csv`. I wouldn't recommend doing exactly that, as you'll have a collision if there are multiple files, but you can also capture part of the existing file name and use it to make the renamed files unique:

```
rewritePaths:
  "^spark/(.*)": "my_export-$1.csv"
```